# How the e.m wave equation changes when it is reflected?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

Suppose an e.m wave travelling in the z direction with electric field vectors oscillating in x direction and magnetic field vectors oscillating in y direction with the wave formula of e(x)=Esine(kz-wt) and b(x)=Bsin(kz-wt),How the quantities k,w,t and the phase(kz-wt) changes with respect to the objects that reflects,if the initial values of the quantities are some constant.

Answer (score 1):

For reflection at a perfect metallic mirror in the z-plane, k changes sign and the wave changes sign, so it continues as $-\sin (-kz-wt)$. In general for perpendicular incidence the amplitude reflectivity is $R_A=\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}$. The intensity reflectivity is $R=\left| \frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2} \right|^2$. For real refractive indices - lossless media -there is a sign change if $ n_2 \gt n_1 $. An example is the transition from air to glass, which of course transmits most of the intensity. Metals have a high conductivity and therefore a high *imaginary* part of the refractive index. Therefore they have a high reflectivity. There is a sign change since usually $|n_2| >> |n_1|$.

Comment: How it will channge for materials like wood.wall?